# Printing definition of anonymous functions using toString

Tags: javascript

I was wondering can we print the definition of anonymous function similarly we do with named functions.

```
function test() { console.log("in test function."); }
test.toString();

//Output
//"function test() { console.log("in test function."); }"

//Example : 
function() { 
 /*Code to print definition of the this function.*/
 console.log("in test function.") 
}
```

Comment: and why couldn't you? you didn't try anything, did you?

Comment: I want to do it from within the function. function() { /* Magic code */  console.log("test") }

Comment: why does it have to be anonymous? Just give it a name...

Comment: Because it can be any function, at runtime, I dont know the name of the function.

Comment: @UlysseBN Any solution?

Comment: You have to give a little bit more context for I to answer...

Comment: @UlysseBN I basically want to monkey patch any function and based of its definition want to put some checks on arguments. I hope I'm not making it more complex.

Comment: I have one but i really is limited, you'd better [edit] your  question with a real [mcve] that is linked to it. For now it just look like a silly question since your example could be solved by naming it (or using Kurt's answer)

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
(function(){console.log("anonymous")}).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee), however this is pretty bad practice and deprecated in ES5:

```js
(function () { console.log(arguments.callee.toString()) })()
```